# DevExpress CheckEdit Control - Place label part on left

Tags: devexpress

How do I place the label portion of a DevExpress CheckEdit control to the left of the checkbox?

Comment: Note: I am adding this question because I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the internet but a friend of mine showed me how to set this property

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go to the Properties of the CheckEdit and navigate to the special DevExpress *Properties* item. You will find a item called *GlyphAlignment*, set this to **Far** and the label will be on the left portion of the control